# Why do I have to define BufferedWriter argument as Writer in function signature?

Tags: java, csv

I wrote the following method:

```
protected void writeCSV(BufferedWriter out, String s) {
    try {
        out.write('"');
        out.write(s.replaceAll("\"", "\"\""));
        out.write('"');
        out.write(',');
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "IOException");
    }
}
```

It is called like this:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath.toString()), "UTF-8"));
writeCSV(out, "CSV cell");
```

Eclipse doesn't like this and requires me to change the type of the first argument in the method's signature to `Writer`. I know `BufferedWriter` extends `Writer`, but why isn't out recognized as a `BufferedWriter`?

Comment: What type is out (calling method, not parameter)??? Did you per chance declare it as `Writer`?

Comment: `Eclipse doesn't like this` doesn't help us. What is the message you get?

Comment: Show the declaration of `out` correctly ...

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. The error is: The method writeCSV(BufferedWriter, String) in the type yadiyada is not applicable for the arguments (Writer, String).

Comment: Then in your line `out = new BufferedWriter(...` `out` is a `Writer` and not a `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Also, don't forget to call `out.close()` when you finish writing.

Answer (score 0):

Looser pointed me to the answer. `out` is simply declared as `Writer` before it is instantiated as `BufferedWriter`. Duh...

Comment: In other words your title is back to front. It wasn't the declaration, it was the use that was the problem. However declaring a method to take a Writer rather than a BufferedWriter is preferable if possible, on polymorphism grounds.

Comment: Do you mean the less specific type is preferable because that means the method will be usable with other kinds of `Writer`? Or is there some deeper reason?